# Why this issue with Workbench?

Tags: warning-messages, workbench

I just installed the current version of Eclipse and then the current version of Workbench 2 by following the online instructions at the Wolfram site for installing it as a plugin. I can create a project with .m and .nb files. I created a very simple function as a module in the .m file. I can call the function in the notebook and get a correct result. But when I set a breakpoint, I get the error seen below.

The function is simple, with a single breakpoint set. What happens is that the breakpoint is ignored, the errors are output, followed by the correct result for the function call.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Here is the function:

[image]

Here is the result of the call:

```
x = f[1, 2, 3]
```

> JLink`Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: MathLinkException: 7: MathLink machine number overflow.
>
> JLink`JavaNew::fail: Error calling constructor for class com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaStackFrame.
>
> JLink`Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: MathLinkException: 7: MathLink machine number overflow.
>
> JLink`JavaNew::fail: Error calling constructor for class com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaStackFrame.
>
> JLink`Java::argx: Method named handleBreakpoint defined in class com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaBreakpointHandler was called with an incorrect number or type of arguments. The arguments, shown here in a list, were {27668229269427709719,{« JavaObject[com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaStackFrame]»,« JavaObject[<<52>>]»,$Failed,$Failed,« JavaObject[<<52>>]»,« JavaObject[com.wolfram.eclipse.MEET.debug.MathematicaStackFrame]»},False}.

EDIT: I reported this to Tech Support. I received the following reply:

"It does appear that breakpoints in Workbench are not behaving properly with small pieces of test code. I have forwarded an issue report to our developers with the information you provided. I also included your contact information in my report.
As a possible workaround, I have only seen these errors occur with very short pieces of code. Setting breakpoints in a less trivial case appear to work as intended."

Comment: By current version of Eclipse you mean 4.9, yes? Which operating system and which Java version are you using?

Comment: I should have listed that. I am using Windows 7 X64 and Java JDK Version 8 build 192. I have the Java an C/C++ IDEs installed as well as Wolfram. The Eclipse is Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800. If this is a version issue, I would be happy to re-install with versions others find to be working.

Comment: And thank you, Kuba, for reformatting my post.

Comment: Something interesting: When I look at the Start menu items under Eclipse, I see "Eclipse Cpp 2018-09" and "Eclipse Java 2018-09" but no start entry for Wolfram. Is this expected?